# Kernels of Hopf algebra homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, hopf-algebras

Let $f:A \to B$ be a homomorphism of Hopf algebras. I think that the subset $N:= \{a \in A \, |\, f(a) \in \mathbb{C}\cdot 1_B \, \}$ is a normal sub-Hopf algebra of $A$ (even though I am not sure if $f\otimes f \circ \Delta(a) \in \mathbb{C} 1_B \otimes \mathbb{C}1_B$ is sufficient for $\Delta(a) \in N\otimes N$..). If this is true, one can check that the ideal $AN^+$, where $N^+=ker(\epsilon_A|_{N})$, is in the kernel of $f$. Is it actually equal to $kerf$?

**EDIT**: Okay, this is clear, since $f(a)=0=0\cdot1_B$ implies $a\in N$, so we have $\epsilon_{A}|_N(a)=\epsilon_{B}\circ f(a)=0$, thus $a \in N^+$. In particular, we have $AN^+=N^+$. It remains to show that $N$ is a subcoalgebra of $A$..

Comment: I have asked a related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2786192/is-the-preimage-of-a-subcoalgebra-a-subcoalgebra), maybe you happen to know the answer, or a counterexample? If your $N$ is a subcoalgebra, then it is necessarily normal.

Comment: @Jo Be Thx for the suggestion! Even though $N$ might not be a subcoalgebra, I think we always  have $N^+=ker\,f$

Comment: Yes, you showed $\ker f\subset N^+$, and the other way is pretty much just
$$0 = \epsilon_A(n) = (\epsilon_B\circ f)(n) = \epsilon_B(\lambda 1_B) = \lambda\ ,$$ where $f(n) = \lambda 1_B$, so $N^+ \subset \ker f$.

Comment: As for your "even though I am not sure if...", see Darij's counterexample on my question. In that context I think $$(\epsilon\otimes\epsilon)\circ \Delta (\epsilon^{-1}(0)) = 0 = 0\otimes 0$$
would be an argument showing that that check is insufficient.